# proof that $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

proof that $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $1$.

WTS: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $\left| \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} - 1 \right| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N = ________ > 0

Suppose $n > N$, then $\left| \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} - 1\right| = \left| \frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}  \right| = \left| \frac{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{1+1/n}+1)}{\sqrt{n}}  \right| = \sqrt{1+1/n} + 1$

How would I prove this? I'm confused how to do this using epsilon delta

Comment: Choose N = $\left\lceil \dfrac1{2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2} \right\rceil$. Then $\sqrt{1+\dfrac1n} < \sqrt{1+2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2}-1 = \varepsilon$.

Comment: And there is a typo: $\sqrt{1+1/n}+1$ should be $\sqrt{1+1/n}-1$. (This occurred twice.)

Comment: @Tree Garen, you have a wrong sign in the last two expressions: the last term should be $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$|\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} -1|=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} -1  = \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} =\dfrac{(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}) }$
$ = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})} \lt \dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n}-1\right|<\epsilon,$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n}-1<\epsilon,$$

$$\frac{n+1}n<(1+\epsilon)^2,$$

$$n>\frac1{2\epsilon+\epsilon^2}.$$

This relation gives you a bound for $N(\epsilon)$, which is always defined.